# multiplication of real numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic

Assume that the number is known to be a right identity for multiplication of real numbers: (∀x)(x⋅1=x)

a. Prove that the number must automatically also be a left identity: (∀x)(1⋅x=x)

b. Prove that the number is the only right identity for multiplication of real numbers.

I get that you would use a two column proof but I do not know to start it. Can someone help me understand how to prove this? I am really struggling how to prove this. This makes sense but I am not sure how to start proving it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What do you have to work with?  Presumably not commutativitiy because then the problem is trivial.  Do you have associativity?  How is multiplication defined?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously we are not to assume that the number "1" **is** the unique multiplicative identity of the real numbers but what **can** we assume?  If we can use the fact that multiplication of the real numbers is commutative then the fact that a left identity is also a right identity is trivial.  As for the fact that the multiplicative identity is unique assume that, to the contrary there exist two multiplicative identities, i1 and i2.  If we can use the fact that multiplication distributes over addition then for any non-zero A, Ai1= Ai2= A.  Since A1= Ai2, Ai1- Ai2= A(i1- i2)= A(i1- i2)= 0.  If, finally, we can use the fact that a field has no "zero divisors" then, since A is non-zero, i1= i2= 0 so i1= i2.